# Vue 3 how to correctly update data in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, highcharts, vuejs3

### Trouble updating data in Highcharts with Vue.js 3

I have a small webapp with **Vue.js 3** that shows a **Highcharts** Chart and some statistics, with global buttons for time-filters (All, Year, Month, Week).
The data of my Highchart chart needs to change, whenever one of the global buttons was pressed.
I used this vue3 wrapper for Highcharts: [Wrappers Github](https://github.com/smithalan92/vue3-highcharts)

Displaying the initial data (all) works like a charm, but when it comes to updating the data, it is really slow. That makes me think that I am doing something wrong with updating the data.

I uploaded a video of my problem on YT: https://youtu.be/GEjHqoAElgI

Additionally I created a **minimal reproducible example** on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-goldwasser-zq8je?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
*It consists of a Chart.vue component, which gets its property "data" updated, when the button "Update Data" is pressed. The button can be toggled multiple times, and it will always take several seconds until the chart is updated.*

Tried giving my component with the Chart the data as property, and have a watcher on that data, to update the Chart whenever the data changes.
This works, but updating the chart takes forever (3-5 seconds).
What is the recommended way of doing something like that?

This is my component:

```js
<template>
  <VueHighcharts
    class="hc"
    :options="options"
    :deepCopyOnUpdate="true"
    :redrawOnUpdate="true"
    :oneToOneUpdate="false"
    :animateOnUpdate="false"
  />
</template>

<script>
import VueHighcharts from "vue3-highcharts";

export default {
  name: "CoinChart",
  components: {
    VueHighcharts,
  },
  props: {
    stats: [Object],
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        title: {
          text: "Coins",
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "ETH",
            data: [],
          },
          {
            name: "BTC",
            data: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
  watch: {
    stats: {
      immidiate: true, // as pointed out in the commments, this line does not do anything
      handler: function (val) {
        // create data for chart
        const eth = new Array();
        const btc = new Array();
        this.options.series[0].data = [];
        this.options.series[1].data = [];

        for (let i in val) {
          eth.push([val[i].time * 1000, val[i].coinsPerHour]);
          btc.push([val[i].time * 1000, val[i].btcPerHour]);
        }

        // set to chart
        this.options.series[0].data = eth;
        this.options.series[1].data = btc;
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is driving me crazy, spent 4hours today on trying to fix it, with no success. Even thought about switching to Chart.js, but apparently there is no real support for Vue.js 3 either.

Comment: In order to improve performance one has to be able to debug and trace the code. We can't debug or trace code you're presenting in a video. Consider creating a [mcve] on codesanbox.io or similar, making sure the reported problem is reproducible. Also note a `watch` property doesn't have an `immidiate` property. If you used an IDE, it would have highlighted the typo.

Comment: @tao Thank you for your reply. I added a minimal reproducible example to my original post: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-goldwasser-zq8je?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I thought I made a trivial mistake in my problematic component, and thought it would be enough to only post the code above.
The video was just for clarifying the problem, not to trace the bug in my code :)

Comment: the lines of code that cause the problem are when you set the data on the chart.  So, it looks like the chart is slow on update, this might just be the way VueHighcharts does the updates, it doess have some options to increase performance but didn't seem to help.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I found out with my caveman console.log debugging ^^
I thought I might have just missed something, since I am not very experienced with either Vue or Highcharts.  
So it's probably just easier to reduce the amount of data I put into my chart?  
Has anyone here by any chance experience if Chart.js can handle that a bit better?  
Although I might need to downgrade my Project to Vue.js 2 for Chart.js, since there is no real support for Vue.js 3 yet.

Comment: The strange thing is, that setting the data the first time (initial data, not with button) works very fast.
But then updating data is slow. Kinda weird, I wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: yeah, I'm not quite sure, I think it should work fast, but something odd is going on, I'd maybe raise an issue on the vuehighcharts github with your reproduction

Comment: I followed your advice and created an issue on github. As soon as there is some new information I will write a follow up. Thanks.

Comment: having said that, I've bypassed vuehighcharts and gone to the chart directly, and its really really slow once it gets over 1000 points, seems to get progressively worse, with 500 points its pretty snappy

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-wind-9nodg

Comment: Maybe I should keep my data below 500points for each filter then. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: maybe, but seems weird.   Not sure if it is possible, but maybe if you can hide and display series, possibly you can add all 4 series and just turn them off and on

Comment: Thats actually probably a really smart Idea, if it works. 
Did you find using `this.$refs.chart.chart.series[0].setData(eth);` made any difference?
With the points being capped to 500, it really feels pretty snappy. Weird that the performance gets so much worse that fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this.

Apparently, when you update the series Highcharts is assigning the new values to the existing series, so that it can calculate any animations. In your case, that's quite heavy, it takes 2-3 seconds, which is what you're seeing.

It's faster to simply throw the chart away (by using a `v-if`) and render it anew with the new dataset:

```html
<template>
  <VueHighcharts v-if="showChart" :options="options" />
</template>
```

```js
import VueHighcharts from "vue3-highcharts"

export default {
  name: 'Chart',
  components: {
    VueHighcharts
  },
  props: {
    series: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    showChart: true
  }),
  computed: {
    options() {
      return {
        //...
        series: this.series
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    series: {
      handler() {
        // this destroys the chart
        this.showChart = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          // this renders a new one, with the new set of data
          this.showChart = true
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that in my project, the performance is much better now, although not as good as in your example, since I have 3 charts in my project that need to be updated, instead of only 1 chart. I think I am still going to reduce the amount of data a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @m4, might be a good idea to disable animations on each series, by passing in `animation: false` to each. (Updated codesandbox example). Another note here is the performance issue has nothing to do with either Vue or the Vue3 wrapper. It's entirely related to how HC tracks data changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your help I could get it to work snappy enough for my usecase. The performance did get a bit better when I reduced the amount of data a little bit. You can check it out if you are interested: https://infallible-euclid-c34bae.netlify.app/ 

And thanks again for your help.